# variable didn't change while another variable changes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to convert `sessionlength` to seconds and save it in a variable called `totalTime` (`totalTime` = `sessionlength` * 60).
In my script, user can click the button to increase/decrease `sessionlength`.
But the problem is totalTime didn't change with `sessionlegnth` changed.
Can anyone point out where did I go wrong? thanks in advance!

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('pomodoroTimer',function pomodoroTimer($scope) {
    $scope.breaklength = 5;
    $scope.sessionlength = 25; 
    $scope.totalTime = $scope.sessionlength * 60;

    $scope.decreaseNumber = function() {
      $scope.sessionlength--;
    };

    $scope.increaseNumber = function() {
      $scope.sessionlength++;
    };  
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not recalculating the total time after session length changes, You can do it like this:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.breaklength = 5;
    $scope.sessionlength = 25; 
    $scope.calcTotalTime = function(){
      $scope.totalTime = $scope.sessionlength * 60;
    }
    
    $scope.decreaseNumber = function() {
      $scope.sessionlength--;
     $scope.calcTotalTime();
    };
    $scope.increaseNumber = function() {
      $scope.sessionlength++;
      $scope.calcTotalTime();
    };
    
    $scope.calcTotalTime();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
 <button ng-click="increaseNumber()">Increase</button>
 <button ng-click="decreaseNumber()">Decrease</button>
 <br>
 Session Length:{{sessionlength}}<br>
 Total Time:{{totalTime}} <br>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.calcTotalTime(); should be added into decreaseNumber method as well.

Comment: Why have you added `calcTotalTime` in the `$scope`? This function won't be used in view.

Comment: @alexmac i added so that whenever sessionlength changes. it will calculate the time. Sorry i didn't understand what you mean by it will not be used in view?

Comment: I mean instead of this `$scope.calcTotalTime = function()` use this - `function calcTotalTime()`.

Comment: @alexmac both are fine but i think in angular  $scope.calcTotalTime = function()  is more appropriate. your suggestion will work too :-)